# Is Trim not good enough for my requirement?

Tags: php, string

```
$x = "''xx''";

echo $x, "\n";
echo trim($x, "'");
```

In this program i want to trim only one single quote from start and one from end.
Trim removes *all* the single quotes from starting and end.

I wish it would remove just *one* quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$x = preg_replace("/^'?(.*?)'?$/", '$1', $x);
```

Or if you have an aversion to using regular expressions:

```
if (substr($x, 0, 1) === "'") {
    $x = substr($x, 1);
}
if (substr($x, -1) === "'") {
    $x = substr($x, 0, -1);
}
```

Comment: i want from start as well as from end

Comment: RegEx is probably not the best for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using preg_replace and the "limit" parameter, the solution isn't too rough:

```
$str = preg_replace("/'/", "", $str, 1);
$str = strrev( preg_replace("/'/", "", strrev($str), 1) );
```

http://ideone.com/RhqglD

Answer (score 0):

Solution without regular expressions.

```
$string = "'test'";
if ($string[0] === "'") {
    $string = substr($string, 1);
}
if ($string[strlen($string) - 1] === "'") {
    $string = substr($string, 0, -1);
}
```